# get children from current variable (taxonomy) via shortcode

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, children

I am working on a portfolio site and I need to modify this part. It is a filter of categories, placed via a shortcode.

I want to show only the children categories of the selected category of my custom post type.... but I dont know how to call the parent variable to use it... I want to declare a variable for the parent so I can use it in the terms array...

```
add_shortcode( 'zee_portfolio', function( $atts, $content = null ){
$atts = shortcode_atts(
array(
'column' => '3',
'category' => '0'
), $atts);

extract($atts);

$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_type'      =>  'zee_portfolio'
);

if(  $category > '0' ){
$args['tax_query'] = array(
  array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'taxonomy' => 'cat_portfolio',
    'field' => 'term_id',
    'terms' => $category
    )
  );
 }

$portfolios = get_posts( $args );

ob_start();

if(count($portfolios)>0){ ?>
<div id="portfolio" class="clearfix">
<ul class="portfolio-filter">
<li><a class="btn btn-default active" href="#" data-filter="*"><?php _e('All',TEXTDOMAIN); ?></a></li>
<?php 
$terms = get_terms('cat_portfolio', array('hide_empty'=> true));
foreach ($terms as $term) {
  ?>
  <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>
  <?php
}
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally notice what is it that I have to do! :D
The variable was already set in the array in the shortcode atts.

All I had to do was set the parent=$category in the before the filter:

```
$terms = get_terms('cat_portfolio', array('hide_empty'=> true, 'parent'=> $category));
```

For wordpress developers maybe this is very easy but I am learning.
Hope this helps someone.